# How to set up /etc/hosts to access a subfolder like it's a root folder (on a Mac)

Tags: macos, apache, server, localhost

I am setting up a new machine. I have it configured to use a Sites folder and localhost to access it. Using Apache, everything installed via Homebrew.

Sites folder

- site1
- site2

In the browser

- localhost/site1/index.html
- localhost/site2/index.html

That part works fine.

The problem is that site1 and site2 think localhost is the root folder (which it is) but I want them to think localhost/site1 and localhost/site2 are the root folders for those sites.

Is this something I can do with /etc/hosts or some other trickery?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a combination of /etc/hosts and Apache VirtualHosts. Here are the steps I took:

1. Establish the directories where you want to serve them from (this will become your DocumentRoot). In my case /Users/myusername/Sites/site1
2. Edit your /etc/hosts file to include your new "domain name" (this will become your ServerName). In my case site1.com

   127.0.0.1 site1.com

   ::site1.com
3. Create an Apache Virtual Host ... there are different ways to go about this, but I used Homebrew to install Apache, so for me, there is a file here: /opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf. I copied the examples provided using DocumentRoot and ServerName as noted above.
4. Update this file /opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/httpd.conf to uncomment this line

   Include /opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
5. Restart Apache